# How do I find the derivative of an integral?

Tags: calculus

$$g(x) = \int_{x^2 + 11}^{3} \frac{dt}{t} $$

I am not sure how to approach this, do I take the antiderivative and then minus the lower limit from upper limit plugged into the antiderivative?

I think it is like this perhaps:

$$f(3) - f(x^2 +11) = (3^2)/2 - (x^2 + 11)^2 /2$$

EDIT: I did the anti derivative wrong too

Comment: Hint: What is the antiderivative of $1/t$?

Comment: Leibniz's rule. But remember that in this problem you have $\int_a^b dt\frac{1}{t}=\log\left|t\right|\bigg|_a^b$

Comment: just realized I did the anti derivative wrong as well.

Comment: Write $g(x)$ as $F(3) - F(x^2+11)$ and use the Chain Rule, along with linearity.

Comment: Why do we use the chain rule? What do I look for to determine what rule to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Something that helps to solve this kind of problems would be letting the antiderivative of $1/t$ be $G(x)$. Hence:

$g(x) = G(3) - G(x^{2} + 11)$

If we want to differentiate the expression (the derivative of the antiderivative will be the function itself):

$g'(x) = -\displaystyle\frac{2x}{x^{2} + 11}$

Where this result follows from the chain rule, as $G'(f(x)) = g(f(x))f'(x)$, where $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of $g(x)$. This usually helps if we have a more complicated function to integrate such as $e^{-x^{2}}$ and so on.

Comment: How did we apply the chain rule here?

Comment: because $G(x)=\ln{|t|}|_{x^2+11}^{3}=\ln{3}-\ln{x^2+11}$